# I have an iframe in my Blazor server app razor page in that an external URL is defined. How can I force to refresh (reload) this url using a button?

Tags: c#, url, razor, iframe, blazor

I have a Blazor server app. In one of the razor pages there is shown an external URL (...index.php) in an iframe. I have some buttons that are writing some information into a exchange txt file.
After pressing each button the URL is not changing. I just have to recall the URL, so that the called index.php shall read the new data in the exchange file. How can I force to refresh or reload the URL in my iframe? My Code is:

```
@page "/explorer"
@using System.Diagnostics
@using System.IO;
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor
<html>
<body>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => { @Drive_Letter="C"; File_Explorer();})">C:\</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => { @Drive_Letter="D"; File_Explorer();})">D:\</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => { @Drive_Letter="E"; File_Explorer();})">E:\</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(() => { @Drive_Letter="F"; File_Explorer();})">F:\</button>


<iframe name="web" src=@URL_Explorer width="1500px"
        height="800px" frameBorder="0">
</iframe>


@code{
    
    public static string CurrentUserName { get; set; }
    public static string CurrentUserName_trimmed { get; set; }
    public string user_path_total;
    public static string Drive_Letter;
    public string URL_Explorer { get; set; }="";

    public void File_Explorer()
    {
        
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(exchange_file, append: false))
        {
            writer.Write("\\\\" + Connect2.MAE_IP_Win + "\\" + Drive_Letter + "$");
            writer.Close();
        }
        
        URL_Explorer = "https://server:8092/index.php" ;
    }


}
```

Comment: try adding `@key=@Drive_Letter` to the `iframe` - when Drive_Letter changes, Blazor will dispose the existing iframe and create a new one

Comment: Yes, this was the solution I was looking for! Great! Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

You try with StateHasChanged() after change the url?

Comment: I have tried this also but without succes. The suggestion from @Mister Magoo was the correct solution.